# What is the PKCS#11 provider DLL for CAC Cards and where do I find it?

Tags: java, dll, pkcs#11, cac

I want to use the PKCS#11 provider of my CAC card but don't know where to find the DLL for it. My CAC card did not come with any software and I cannot find enough information on the internet. Can anyone here tell me what is the name of the file and where I can get it from?

Comment: Ask the vendor. Off topic.

Comment: CACSupport@mail.mil, http://www.cac.mil/common-access-card/developer-resources/

Comment: Done way back. Didn't respond!

Comment: So send the hardware back and use a vendor that supports their product.